# PHP Redirect to an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, anchor, href

I want to navigate from another page to the bottom of the home page.

Where section that I want to navigate to on the home page is defined by:

```
<div name="about" id="about" class="about-us">
```

Everywhere I read it says all you have to do to link to this page and this location is say:

```
<a href="/public_html/index.php#about">Link to bottom of home page.</a>
```

However, it does not work. There has got to be something simple that I am over looking.

EDIT:

Whenever I click the link, the browser does nothing, like it is not a link.

Take this example:

I am on the homepage, I click a link to #about, it scrolls down to #about, no problem.

I am on a page that is not the home page. I click on a link to #about, the browser does nothing, does not even take me back to the home page.

Comment: please add your php redirect code.

Comment: Does it go to anywhere on the page? I suspect this works but you can't reach the bottom of the page because you *are* at the bottom of page. You can't go past the bottom unless you add a lot of whitespace.

Comment: No, I am linking from a different page, so I want to go from a portfolio page, to the bottom of the home page.

Comment: A question about your edit: sounds very much like you have a different problem so? Is the non-homepage link actually clickable?

Comment: Yes, if I take the #about off of `index.php#about` so that it is just `index.php` it takes me to the homepage.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your example will work just fine, so something else is probably preventing the jump. For example, if you have a form on the page that has auto focus.

Comment: I don't have a form on the page per say, but I do have a form modal that can be brought up from any page.